# On-click jquery event

Tags: jquery, onclick

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar icon-white-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar icon-white-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar icon-white-bar"></span>
            </a>

            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav" id='main_root_menu'>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Search<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li id="bag_search"><a href="#"><span class="icon-user icon-white"></span> Bag-Seal</a></li>
                            <li id="docket_search"><a href="#"><span class="icon-wrench icon-white"></span> Docket</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to select `bag-search` when it is clicked. Currently, I'm doing like this. But no event is triggered.

```
$(document).on('click','#main_root_menu .dropdown .dropdown-menu #bag_search',function(){
        $( "#bag_dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
```

Where I'm going wrong>

Comment: The question is, as ID's are unique, why do you need the selector for three parent elements when all you really need is `#bag_search`

Comment: I tried that as well. didnt worked.

Comment: Just use `$(document).on('click','#bag_search', fn)` - ids should be unique. If that doesn't work, please check your console for errors, and edit your OP to include them.

Comment: Where is `#bag_dialog`?

Comment: Just a suggesting: Add only relvent HTML

Comment: @ShaunakD- `#bag_dialog` is there. Even `alert(1)` doesnt work.

Comment: You did include jQuery ***and*** jQuery UI

Comment: And you checked the console for errors ?

Comment: Have you called $( "#bag_dialog" ).dialog({options}) before call the open method? Console errors?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward- Even alert is not woring.

Comment: @user1162512 can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: If a simple alert isn't working, you clearly have errors halting the script. You need to open the console and check for errors, it's been repeated now ten times, and yet you seem to fail to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).on('click','#bag_search',function(){
    $( "#bag_dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

Or

```
 $("#bag_search").click(function(){
    $( "#bag_dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

first write your code in **[document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click','#bag_search',function(){
    $( "#bag_dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
  });
});
```

Comment: Why would that matter when targeting the `document`, it's always ready !

Comment: sorry @adeneo some time code not works as expected when we not write our code in document ready

Comment: have you include jquery and jquery ui with corret path

Answer (score 0):

As id is unique you can use just #bag_search and need to use preventDefault as you have anchor tag inside list:

```
$(document).on('click','#bag_search',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $( "#bag_dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
  });
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tcC29/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code throws error :

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization;
>   attempted to call method 'open'

Don't specify "open" in dialog method. Use as given below :

```
 $( "#bag_dialog" ).dialog();
```

Here is the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/r8dHv/

Answer (score 0):

It should be worked ..

```
$('#bag_search').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    confirm('welcome to bag search');
});
```